# Many requests with final callback, unreliable order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to come up with a resource loader if you will, that will load many remote resources and then execute a final callback (like rendering a DOM based on the retrieve data from these requests).

Here's the function:

```
var ResourceLoader = function () {

    this.requests = new Array();
    this.FinalCallback;

    this.Add = function (request) {
        this.requests.push(request);
    };

    this.Execute = function() {

        for (var x = 0; x < this.requests.length ; x++) {

            var success = this.requests[x].success;

            //if this is the last of the requests...
            if (x == (this.requests.length - 1) && this.FinalCallback) {

                $.when($.ajax({
                            url: this.requests[x].url,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: this.requests[x].error,
                            method: 'GET'
                        }).done(success)).then(this.FinalCallback);
            }
            else {

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.requests[x].url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: this.requests[x].error,
                    method: 'GET'
                }).done(success);                
            }

        }

    };
};
```

And here's how I use it:

```
var apiUrl = Utilities.Api.GetWebApiUrl();
var loader = new Utilities.ResourceLoader();

loader.Add({
    url: apiUrl + 'regions/get',
    success: function (results) {
        Filters.Regions = results;
    }
});

loader.Add({
    url: apiUrl + 'currentfactors/get/83167',
    success: function (results) {
        Filters.NbrEmployees = results;
    }
});

loader.Add({
    url: apiUrl + 'currentfactors/get/83095',
    success: function (results) {
        Filters.Industries = results;
    }
});


loader.FinalCallback = RenderBody;
loader.Execute();

function RenderBody() {
    console.log('render...');
}
```

Obviously, I'm expecting `RenderBody` to be executed last. But that's not what happening. What's ironic is that I remember doing something like that before, but lost the code... Looks like I'm having a brainfart here.

Comment: `I'm expecting RenderBody to be executed last` - the problem is, asynch requests like that, as you've noted, don't occur in sequence, so you need to, rather than check if the request is the final one, check if the *response* is the final one

Comment: HTTP requests finish when they finish. There's no guaranteed order. You can keep your own counter and increment it in the "success" callback so that you know when you're handling the last response.

Comment: @Pointy So in `ResourceLoader` I'd need to inject a counter check in the provided success callbacks ? I want `ResourceLoader` to handle this itself.

Comment: OK, well do it some other way then. The basic fact of the matter is that you can't control the order in which your HTTP requests will complete.

Comment: As you've tagged this question [tag:promise] - look at using `Promise.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged with [promise](/questions/tagged/promise) - here's a really clean solution that uses `Promise.all`

```
this.Execute = function() {
  Promise.all(this.requests.map(function(request) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: request.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: request.error,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(request.success);
  })).then(this.FinalCallback);
};
```

or ... using JQuery when

```
this.Execute = function() {
  $.when.apply($, this.requests.map(function(request) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: request.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: request.error,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(request.success);
  })).then(this.FinalCallback);
};
```

Comment: Didn't try it yet, looks clean indeed. How compatible is it with most recent browsers ? (IE, Edge, Chrome, etc.) ?

Comment: no IE without a Promise polyfill (see [MDN promise page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#See_also) for a link to an [OK polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/) ... or maybe use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), that seems popular) ... but I've updated with `jquery.when` alternative - which shouldn't give a problem with IE

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. I'll stick to the jQuery alternative for now.

Answer (score 0):

Es6 `Promise` has solutions for your problem, there is no need to reinvent it unless the loading of resource groups is a specific goal to abstract.  Set up a `Promise` object for each resource request, using the constructor to assign the resolve and reject callbacks appropriately for the XHR.  Keep a collection (any `Iterable` will do) of `individualPromise.then(individualCallback)` results.  Your final product is obtained by `Promise.all(collectionOfPromises).then(finalCallback)`.